# Angular 4 HttpClientModule

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

How does this code change wrt to the new HttpClientModule, where mapping from response.json() is not required.

```
    //uses Http
    getLegalTerms(): Observable<legalterm[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._legalTermUrl)
        .map((response: Response) => <legalterm[]> response.json());
    }
```

i get nothing back if I do the following

```
    //uses HttpClientModule
    getLegalTerms(): Observable<legalterm[]> {
        return this._http.get<legalterm[]>(this._legalTermUrl)
    }
```

I am subscribing in the component class in the same way in either case

```
     ngOnInit() {
        this._legalTermService.getLegalTerms()
         .subscribe((legalTerms: LegalTerm[])  =>  {
         this.legalTerms = legalTerms;
      })
    }
```

I get data in the grid with Http but no data in grid with HttpClient

Thank you!
Anand

Comment: The code looks correct. What do you mean you get nothing back? The angular http observable does not run unless you subscribe to it.

Comment: @LLai I am subscribing to this method in the component class

Comment: so the http request is firing and you do receive legalTerms?

Comment: @LLai - yes, answered below

Comment: What you have is correct. With `this._http.get<legalterm[]>` you are saying the http response will return type `legalterm[]` which matches with your method output type `Observable<legalterm[]>`. This is the correct way to strongly type your getLegalTerms method

Comment: Yes, it does work. not sure why this would not work before...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be,

```
 getLegalTerms(): Observable<legalterm[]> {
        return this._http.get(this._legalTermUrl)
        //.map((response: Response) => <legalterm[]> response);
       .map((response: Response) => <any> response);
 }
```

Comment: I gave the upvote as it was a correct answer. but somebody gave the downvote for no reason (might be the question owner I guess). these people don't have the courage to appreciate those who help

Comment: @Sajeetharan - thanks but the problem is type Reponse cannot be converted to LegalTerm[]

Comment: try changing as any and then convert inside the component

Comment: This *IS* correct for the OLD Http not the NEW HttpClient. If you are using the new HttpClient you should *NOT* need to map. The OP's syntax was correct and this is NOT.